# Непонятная ошибка на некоторых телефонах при запуске сервиса

Tags: android, android-service, android-notification

Здравствуйте. Есть сервис, в котором создается уведомление через startforeground(). 
 Сервис запускается при открытии активити. Заметил, что на некоторых телефонах при открытии активити приложение падает и выдается такая ошибка. В частности на телефоне Galaxy Mega. Проверял на реальных других устройствах (Galaxy j7, grand prime) все нормально. В чем может быть причина?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package ru.test.onlineradio: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=ru.test.onlineradio user=UserHandle{0} id=101 tag=null score=0: Notification(pri=0 contentView=ru.test.onlineradio/0x1090082 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null] 1 action))
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1423)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Метод для создания уведомления

```
private void showNotification() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Intent closeIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    closeIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pCloseIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, closeIntent, 0);

    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Играет: " + track)
            .setContentText("Открыть главное окно")
            .setSmallIcon(img)
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon_stop, "Стоп", pCloseIntent)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.PLAYER_SERVICE_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: приведите код разметки уведомления и как создается Notification

Comment: И еще покажите код как выставляется нотификация `PendingIntent` и т.д.

Comment: В вопрос добавил метод создания уведомления. Самой разметки уведомления у меня нет, я в этом методе все делаю. Я не пойму почему такая ошибка выдается я не использую никаких view чтобы вывести уведомление.